# JFrame always prints out null for variables inside action listener

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, actionlistener

The following program's goal is to ask the user to input a resistor value, then of which the program will output the corresponding colors for each digit. This thus not include all the digits. However, that program is done, I've made an attempt to incorporate JFrame as an extra thing, except I am hung up on how to print the corresponding colors in the action listener.

I asked this question previously however, got limited replies due to forgetting to enter specific tags. However, with the user answer to use ArraysToString did practicly nothing, since the program still managed to print null.

[Cannot refer to non variable inside Action listener (Jframe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824158/cannot-refer-to-non-variable-inside-action-listener-jframe/15824306?noredirect=1#15824306)
The methods below the JFrame are sopposed to gather the information for each color band of the resistor depending on the digit number, where as in the action listener I try and simply print out those colors, but rather it always prints null (3 times)

I have tried viewing various tutorials online, and even the Java API and guidelines, none of which could help. In general I seem unaware of how to incorporate code that is already written into JFrame, whether it's a tedious process, I am willing to corporate and would be very grateful for some insight on how to tackle this predicament.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
//import javax.swing.JFrame;
//import javax.swing.JLabel;
//import javax.swing.JButton;
//import javax.swing.JPanel;
//import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test extends JFrame
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));


    //calling variables
    String input;
    int numInput;

    JLabel l = new JLabel("Hello and welcome to the Program (Press the button to start the instructions");
    //l.setAlignmentX(0);
   // l.setAlignmentY(0);

    //calling arrays
    int [] array = new int [5];
    int [] array2 = new int [3];
    String [] array3 = new String [3];
    String[] colours = {"black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "gray", "white"};


    JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello JFrame");
    f.setSize(500,500);
    //f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    f.add(l);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    //JTextField t = new JTextField(16);


    JPanel p = new JPanel ();
    JButton b = new JButton("Press me") ;
   // b.setAlignmentX(0);
   // b.setAlignmentY(0);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"In the following program you (The user!) will input a number of a resistor value \nThe program will pass the information into methods and then proceed to print out \nThe coorelating colors (Press the button to be asked for input)");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the resistor value"));

        final String [] array3 = new String [3];

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Colors are : " + (Arrays.toString(array3)));



      } 

    });

    p.add(b);
    p.add(l);
    //p.add(t);
    f.add(p);


    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the Program (Press any key to con't)");
    input = myInput.readLine ();

    System.out.println("In the following program you (The user!) will input a number of a resistor value");
    System.out.println("The program will pass the information into methods and then proceed to print out");
    System.out.println("The coorelating colors (Press any key to be asked for input)");
    input = myInput.readLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a resistor value (Note that resistors can only acount to 4 decimal places");
    input = myInput.readLine ();
    numInput = Integer.parseInt (input);

    //colours for values
    array2 = values(array, input, colours);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
      array3[i] = digitColours(array2[i], colours);
      System.out.println(array3[i]);// prints colours for values
    }


    //prints 4th colour for multiplier
    System.out.println(decimalPlaces(input, colours));

  } 

  public static int[] values (int [] digit, String num, String[] colours)
  {

    String holder;
    double numHolder;
    int lengthOfInput;
    int holder2;

    //tollerance
    holder = num.substring(3,4);
    digit[3] = Integer.parseInt(holder);
    holder2 = Integer.parseInt(num);
    // checks to see if above 5
    if(digit[3] < 5){
      digit[3] = digit[3]/holder2 * 100;
    }
      else if(digit[3] > 5){
      digit[3] = 10 - digit[3];
      digit[3] = digit[3]/holder2 * 100;
    }
    System.out.println(digit[3]);

    //Rounding of the input
    lengthOfInput = num.length() - 3;
    numHolder = Double.parseDouble(num);
    numHolder = numHolder/(Math.pow(10,lengthOfInput));
    numHolder = (int)(Math.round(numHolder)+0.5);

    // first three digits
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      holder = num.substring(i,i+1);
      digit[i] = Integer.parseInt(holder);
    }

    //print out for information
    /*System.out.println("The first digit is rounded to:" + (int)digit[0]);
     System.out.println("The second digit is roudned to:" + (int)digit[1]);                   
     System.out.println("The third digit is roudned to:" + (int)digit[2]);  */
    /* */
    return new int[] {digit[0], digit[1],digit[2],digit[3]} ;// return
  }


  public static String digitColours(int decimalPlace, String[] colours){
    //calling additional variables
    String answer;
    answer = colours[decimalPlace];
    return answer;
  }


  //method to find the multiplier
  public static String decimalPlaces(String input, String[] colours){
    //calling additional variables
    int length = input.length();
    String answer;

    length = length - 3;
    answer = colours[length];

    return answer;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array, array3, will always be null since it has been declared that way:

```
        final String[] array3 = new String[3];

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
              "The Colors are : " + (Arrays.toString(array3)));
```

As you can see from the above code, it has never been assigned String objects of any kind and so defaults to null. You must fill it first for it to hold non-null values. Think of an object array similar to an egg crate: unless you fill it with eggs, it will always be empty.

I recommend that you make any variables that you want passed into the inner class, final. But it must be final in the *outer* class, not in the *inner* class:

More importantly, I'd get most all of your code *out* of your main method, out of static-land and into instance-land where it belongs. Then you can use class fields and not have to worry about local final variables. This is what I think the major weakness of your current program -- too much static code and not enough OOP-compliant classes and objects.

Your other problem is that you appear to be trying to mix a Swing GUI with a console program that gets user input both by GUI and by the standard in via a BufferedReader, and this can lead to disaster. I strongly urge you to chose one or the other, probably better with the Swing GUI in my opinion and not try to mix these unmixable things.

Comment: Taking my code out of the main method, as in, putting the jframe in it's own method, and creating a constructor for itself?

Comment: @SD: something like that, but it won't be that simple or straightforward I don't think. You'll likely need to do quite a bit of re-write.

Comment: I'll do my best, thanks for the response, and although this JFrame is sort of a bonus mark thing, it certainly is worth going through the hassle of doing.