# Cannot refer to non Final Variable (Array)

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

The following program is supposed to receive user input for a 4 digit color code resistor, then proceed to print it in the JFrame (Currently has it set for both BufferedReader and JFrame) However, I understand that I cannot simply print something in the outer method into an inner method. For instance, I am attempting to print array3 in the action listener after the input goes through, however I get that error.

I attempted to set certain variables to final in the main method, Have searched various pages over the internet and still can't find a solution to my specific problem. I did ask this question previously on here, however, it lead to more confusion because of attempting to re write my code JFrame in its own method lead to near chaos, thus me having to result back to my original code. I'm wondering how I can take that user input and pass it on to those methods below On the JFrame, because What I'm attempting right now certainly doesn't work.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test extends JFrame
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    //calling variables
    String input;
    int numInput;

    JLabel l = new JLabel("Hello and welcome to the Program");
    l.setAlignmentX(0);
    l.setAlignmentY(0);

    //calling arrays
    int [] array = new int [5];
    int [] array2 = new int [3];
    String [] array3 = new String [3];
    String[] colours = {"black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "gray", "white"};
    String[] tollerance = {"red", "gold", "silver", "no band"};



    JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello JFrame");
    f.setSize(500,500);
    //f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    f.add(l);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //JTextField t = new JTextField(16);

    /*SodaMachine machine = new SodaMachine(); //class name
     JButton cokeButton = new JButton();
     cokeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed() {
     machine.dispenseCoke();
     }
     }); */



     JPanel p = new JPanel ();
     JButton b = new JButton("Press me") ;
     b.setAlignmentX(0);
     b.setAlignmentY(0);

     test x = new test();
     b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"In the following program you (The user!) will input a number of a resistor value \nThe program will pass the information into methods and then proceed to print out \nThe coorelating colors (Press the button to be asked for input)");
     int number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the resistor value"));

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Colors are : " + array3[i]);

     } 

     });

     p.add(b);
     p.add(l);
     //p.add(t);
     f.add(p);


     System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the Program (Press any key to con't)");
     input = myInput.readLine ();

     System.out.println("In the following program you (The user!) will input a number of a resistor value");
     System.out.println("The program will pass the information into methods and then proceed to print out");
     System.out.println("The coorelating colors (Press any key to be asked for input)");
     input = myInput.readLine();

     System.out.println("Enter a resistor value (Note that resistors can only acount to 4 decimal places");
     input = myInput.readLine ();
     numInput = Integer.parseInt (input);


     //colours for values
     array2 = values(array, input, colours);
     for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
     array3[i] = digitColours(array2[i], colours);
     System.out.println(array3[i]);// prints colours for values
     }

     //prints 4th colour for multiplier
     System.out.println(decimalPlaces(input, colours));
     //tollerance band
     System.out.println(tollerance(input, tollerance));

     } 

     public static int[] values (int [] digit, String num, String[] colours)
     {

     String holder;
     double numHolder;
     int lengthOfInput;
     int holder2;

     //Rounding of the input
     lengthOfInput = num.length() - 3;
     numHolder = Double.parseDouble(num);
     numHolder = numHolder/(Math.pow(10,lengthOfInput));
     numHolder = (int)(Math.round(numHolder)+0.5);

     // first three digits
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     holder = num.substring(i,i+1);
     digit[i] = Integer.parseInt(holder);
     }

     return new int[] {digit[0], digit[1], digit[2]} ;// return
     }

     public static String digitColours(int decimalPlace, String[] colours){
     //calling additional variables
     String answer;
     answer = colours[decimalPlace];
     return answer;
     }


     //method to find the multiplier
     public static String decimalPlaces(String input, String[] colours){
     //calling additional variables
     int length = input.length();
     String answer;

     length = length - 3;
     answer = colours[length];

     return answer;
     }

     public static String tollerance(String num, String[] tollerance){

     String holder;
     int holder2;
     double perError;

     //tollerance
     holder = num.substring(3,4);
     perError = Double.parseDouble(holder);
     holder2 = Integer.parseInt(num);
     // checks to see if above 5
     if(perError < 5){
     perError = perError/holder2 * 100;
     }
     else if(perError > 5){
     perError = 10 - perError;
     perError = perError/holder2 * 100;
     }

     //changing for colour
     if(perError <= 2){
     perError = 0;
     }else if(perError <= 5){
     perError = 1;
     }else if(perError <= 10){
     perError = 2;
     }else if(perError <= 20){
     perError = 3;
     }

     return tollerance[(int)perError];
     }
     }
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but your class is claiming for being refactored.

Comment: By the way, the problem is that you can't use a method variable inside a local-method inner class at least that it is declared as `final`.

Comment: [Aqua's answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15824306/139010) explains the compile error perfectly well. Many Java programmers attempting to use Swing run into this error message. I strongly suggest that you whittle the code down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Basic compiler error questions like this one, asked endlessly, are not widely useful unless asked in a general manner that has some potential to help future programmers who have a similar issue.

Comment: The link does not provide An example code?

Comment: The code example should be yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your short-term problem is that you're trying to use a non-final variable local to a method in an inner class. This can be solved by either using a final variable or a class field (here, because it is being used in a static method, it must be static).

But having said that, your over-all problem ***again*** is that you've got everything shoved into the static main method (or static method of any kind for that matter). You absolutely need to create classes that can be used to create objects. I believe that we've discussed this recently before.

---

**Edit**

I have changed my mind -- your "model", your code that decides what color String to display probably can consist of nothing but static methods. It could have a method that looks something like this:

```
public class ResistorColorsUtility {
   // create a String array, ALL_COLORS, as a constant that the methods 
   // of this class can use.
   private static final String[] ALL_COLORS = { "black", "brown", "red",
         "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "gray", "white" };

   public static String[] getColorsForValue(int value) {
      // code in here will create an array of Strings for the value given and
      // return it 

      // here use value int to find all the appropriate colors
      // create String array called result to hold the color Strings
      String[] result = ......; // you've got to create this code!

      return result; // return the result
   }

   // it will likely have other public methods that the GUI could use

   // and other private methods that it will only use internally 
   // and will not be used by other classes
}
```

The GUI has fields for input and for display of result, and a button to find out when the user wants to see the result. The main method does little more than to get the program running, here to create a JFrame to put the main GUI code's JPanel in and then display that JFrame.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

// A very simple GUI to illustrate a point
public class ResistorGui extends JPanel {
   private JButton findColorButton = new JButton("Find Colors");
   private JTextField valueInputField = new JTextField(2);
   private JTextField resultField = new JTextField(15);

   public ResistorGui() {
      // user shouldn't be able to edit result field
      resultField.setEditable(false);
      resultField.setFocusable(false);

      findColorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // all program logic is in here

            // get value String from valueInputField
            // translate to int
            // call utility method from ResistorColorsUtil class!
            // display result in resultField
         }
      });

      add(new JLabel("Value:"));
      add(valueInputField);
      add(findColorButton);
      add(new JLabel("Result:"));
      add(resultField);
   }


   // all main does is to display the GUI, that's it
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ResistorGui mainPanel = new ResistorGui();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ResistorGui");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure on how to create those classes, to create new objects.

Comment: @SD: usually the order of things is to learn how to create classes and objects *first* before attempting to code complex programs including GUI's. You can learn about them here: [Lesson: Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).

Comment: I actually just managed to get the program to give me different errors, which seem easier to fix by simply creating another method for the jframe while everything else goes to the main. The errors simply state that array3[i] can't be resolved to a variable, I'm thinking i can pass this into the new non static method and make it work, except the Jframe is not launching only the Regular input screen is.

Comment: @SD: you're doing nothing but reinforcing bad habits and ignoring all the advice we've been giving you if you simply persevere and keep most of this code in static methods. Since we're just wasting our breath trying to give you decent advice that is constantly ignored, why even try to advise you?

Comment: Because I have spent countless hours, days, trying to understand this. By the fact of me putting the effort in, seems to guide me to belief that you guys are not willing to work effectively with me. I've read various tutorials and those websites, and simply put they just don't make sense. I don't have all the time in the world to keep reading and reading and reading, I'd like some input in lamens terms that I can actually understand and seemingly apply to my program.

Comment: I do apologize if I've sounded a bit rude on my previous comment and others. But simply put, I've never been this stressed while writing a program, and not understanding a certain concept certainly does not help my ego.

Comment: @SD: In layman's terms: 1) create a class that does the logic of your program and nothing else, that does nothing else but takes resister values and returns Color arrays, that has *no* static fields or methods. 2) Create a GUI that uses an object of this class, that has *no* static fields or methods other than the main method, and that can call methods on the object of the first class and uses the results to change what it displays. Most importantly, read about classes and object sin the link I've provided so you can do this.

Comment: This certainly does help, il give it a go. Again I didn't mean to be rude, it's just the frustration is quite annoying to say the least.

Comment: Takes resistor values and returns Color arrays, as in takes the values from user Input of bufferedReader?

Comment: @SD: No. The logic portion of your program should have no user interaction whatsoever. It should have methods that takes input via parameters and returns output via the return statement of the method. Again a Swing GUI should get no input via System.in.

Comment: I'm still in a way confused on the logic method, 'input via parameters' are those parameters coming from the main method of the gui (Main)?

Comment: @SD: hang on a sec...

Comment: I'll be willing to give you the check mark, so long as I can fully understand how to fix this.

Comment: @SD: I don't really care about a check mark. Please see edit to post above.

Comment: @SD: If you want to call a static method on another class, you need to use the class name to call it. For instance if the class Foo has a static `bar()` method, you need to call it like `Foo.bar()`.

Comment: I have converted the input in the field to an integer, I now want to pass that input to the ResistorColorUtility class, to pass it on to further public methods,except simply doing the foo.bar way of passing it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: Oh i just realized that method is not static.